# How do you write a program in javascript that asks the user to enter a list of numbers, and then find the average of the numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

I can't get this program to output the average of the entered prompted numbers by a user. How else should i code it? Any help will be appreciated.

```
var gpas = [];
var gp;
var total = 0;
let count = 0;
var max = 0;
var min = 0;
var out = "";
while (i != "XXX") {
    var i = prompt("Enter a gpa or XXX to Stop");
    if (i != "XXX") {
        gpas.push(i);
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < gpas.length; i++) {
    out += gpas[i];
    out += "<br/>";
}
count++;
total += gpas[i];
var avg = total / count;
out += avg;
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += out + "<br/>";
```

the output is showing "NaN" instead of a valid number.

Comment: Please use `gpas.push(parseInt(i));`

Comment: Some of code after the `for` loop appears to belong inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @FelixKling, which of the codes should belong inside?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a variable that holds the sum of the numbers entered and then just divide it by the total numbers entered.

## First approach *infinite loop* :

The first approach acts as the one you're using. Basically, we'll ask for a new number as long as we don't get the string `"XXX"`.

```js
/** 
* @const output the span where to print the average.
**/
const output = document.getElementById('output');

/**
* @var avg stores the sum of the entered numbers.
* @var i keeps track of the number of numbers entered.
**/
let sum = 0,
  i = 0;
  
/** basically while true increment i **/
while (1 && ++i) {
  /** ask for a number or "XXX" to exit **/
  const n = prompt(`Enter a number or enter "XXX" to exit :`, 0);
  /** if "XXX" is entered break the loop (the only way to break that infinite loop) **/
  if(n == 'XXX') break;
  /** if something else than "XXX" is entered try to cast it to a float  **/
  sum += parseFloat(n);
}

/** print the average **/
output.textContent = (sum / (i - 1)).toFixed(2); /** why dividing by "i - 1" and not only "i" is because "i" is incremented even when we enter "XXX" **/
```

```html
<div>average: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

> This approach is not user friendly (the loop can't be exited unless `"XXX"` is typed) and may consume a lot of resources.

## Second approach *fixed number of numbers* :

This approach asks the user to enter how many number he want to type then we ask him to type as many numbers as the one he typed earlier.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

/**
* @var n the number of numbers the user is going to type.
* @var sum the sum of these numbers.
* @var i a counter used to exit the loop when we reach "n" nummbers typed. 
**/
let n = prompt('How many element do you want to enter ?', 2),
  sum = 0,
  i = 0;
  
/** while i + 1 < n and no need to manually break the loop **/
while (i++ < n) sum += parseFloat(prompt(`Enter a number (${i} remaining) :`, 0));

output.textContent = (sum / n).toFixed(2); /** now we know how many numbers entered from the beging thanks to the variable "n" **/
```

```html
<div>average: <span id="output"></span></div>
```

> `parseFloat` used to parse the numbers (in fact they're strings) entered by the user to floats.
>
> `toFixed` is used to have only two decimal numbers when calculating the average.

Comment: Thank you so much, This actually did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i != "XXX") {
    var i = prompt("Enter a gpa or XXX to Stop");
    if (i != "XXX") {
        gpas.push(parseInt(i)); // we need string to number with `parseInt`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone that contributed. By applying some of the suggestions given, I was able to make it work. I also noticed that the code below does the work too:

`````
 var gpas = [];
 var gp;
var out = "";
while (i != "XXX")
{
var i = prompt("Enter a gpa or XXX to Stop");
if(i != "XXX"){
gpas.push(parseInt(i));
}
}  
     let sum = gpas.reduce((a, b) => {
 return a + b;
}); 

sum;
var avg = (sum/gpas.length);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "average =" + avg + "<br/>";
</script>````
`````